# Inheritance strategy in Hibernate for better performance

Tags: hibernate

In order to capture the logging information of my application to the tables , I am designing three tables as shown in the attached picture.

[image]

**LogType** ( Table is the Static Table ) which has only two columns and two rows fixed Id = 1 , 2 and Type = Info , Debug

INFOLOG( Table ) and DEBUGLOG Tables will have additional respective information .

My Question is which Inheritance Strategy is best suited for such scenario , I think of **Table for Subclass since My super table(Log Type) is constant and wont change** . Please put comments with some annotation examples .

So my base class would be

```
@Entity 
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) 
@MappedSuperclass 
public abstract class LogType implements Serializable 
{ 

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
@Column(name = "LogTypeId", nullable = false, updatable = false) 
private Integer logTypeId; 

@Column(name = "LogTypeName", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10) 
private String logTypeName; 

public LogType() { 
super(); 

} 

public LogType(final Integer logTypeId, final String logTypeName) { 
super(); 
this.logTypeId = logTypeId; 
this.logTypeName = logTypeName; 
} 
}
```

Comment: Well, if you have designed your tables like this, you have already chosen your inheritance strategy. It's the JOINED. with SINGLE_TABLE, you would have a single table instead of 3. With TABLE_PER_CLASS, you would have only 2 tables.

Comment: Unless the top tables is not a superclass for the two other ones, in which case you've already chosen to use TABLE_PER_CLASS

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet , Im not still getting TABLE_PER_CLASS total tables are 2 instead of three please explain in my example .  My parent Table LogType is a static table which only 2 rows and and 2 columns .

Comment: LogType is irrelevant to your inheritance model. It's just that bothe sub-entities have a reference to a LogType. In terms of classes, you have one abstract base class Log, two concrete subclasses Info and Debug, and there is a ManyToOne association between Log and LogType. So, regarding your three inheritance-related classes (Log, Info and Debug), you have just two tables to map them.

Comment: JB Nizet , Thank you for your time , Could you please show me with a small example i.e  How can I map two tables InfoLog and Debug Log ?

Comment: Just like explained in the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-table-per-class, except the base class would be abstract, and there wouldn't be any table for this class.

Comment: Thanks but Still my question is I need to have two rows and 2 columns that is it in the base abstract class LogType  when I annotate with @Entity it would be persisted in the DB right  ? Without persisted how will I be able to insert data to my abstract base class entity ?

Comment: You're confusing inheritance with compisition. An InfoLog *is not* A LogType. An InfoLog *has* a log type (which is Info). Inheritance is for *is a* relationships (a Student is a Person, for example). For has a relationships, you need a ManyToOne association.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139902/discussion-between-ronan-and-jb-nizet).